# Nginx auth_basic not working for a specific url

Tags: authentication, nginx

I would like to password protect one of the URLs I have and I am trying to do it with:

```
 location /about/payment {
    auth_basic           "secured site";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/my.passwd;
}
```

The problem is that I am asked for the username and paasword. AS soon as I put the right username and password, I am getting a 404 Error with this log:

```
*55268 open() "/var/www/mysite.com/deployment/web/about/payment" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.16.0.53, server: ~^(?<branch>\w+)\.mysite\.dev$, request: "GET /about/payment HTTP/1.1", host: "deployment.mysite.dev"
```

EDIT:

The entire nginx conf file is here

```
server {
  listen 80;

  access_log              ...;
  error_log               ...;
  server_name ~^(?<branch>\w+)\.mysite\.dev$  ~^(?<branch>\w+)\.mysite\.com$;
  root /var/www/git/branches/mysite.com/$branch/web;

  location /about/payment {
    auth_basic           "secured site";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/mysite.passwd;
  }

  # strip app_eudev.php/ prefix if it is present
  rewrite ^/app_eudev\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

  # remove trailing slash
  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

  # sitemap rewrite
  rewrite ^/sitemap_(.*)$ /sitemap/$1 last;

  location / {
     try_files $uri @symfonyapp;
  }

  location @symfonyapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app_eudev.php/$1 last;
  }

  location /var/www/dms/ {
      internal;
      alias /var/www/dms/;
  }

  location @htmlimages {
      root /var/www/dms/;
  }

  location ~ /html/.*\.(png|gif|jpg|pdf)$ {
    root ...;
    try_files $uri @htmlimages;
  }

  location /files {
    root ...;
  }

  location /assets {
    root ...;
  }

  location /img {
     root ...
  }

  location ~ \.php(/|$) {
  fastcgi_pass                    127.0.0.1:9001;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS              off;
  }
 }
```

Comment: And what did you expect?

Comment: As written on my 1st sentance, I am expecting "I would like to password protect one of the URLs", so once the password is entered, the url page should open

Comment: Well, it opens. But you don't have that directory. If you have some «catch all» rule, you should use it here too.

Comment: I don't get it. I have a symfony2 project. Should I paste my entire nginx config file?

Comment: Of course you should. But even w/o config I could tell that you must undertand one simple thing: when nginx find location block which processes request it will not look into any other locations. So in this example, nginx found location you've posted and there is nothing about passing request to symphony, so nginx decides to serve static files.

Comment: Thanks Alexy, got it how it works, however, I am not able to figure out what should be included there. I updated my question with the nginx config file

Comment: I guess `root ...; try_files $uri @symfonyapp;` should be enough

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot Alexey, it works as a charm. Could you please naswer the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When nginx find matching `location` that will process request it ignores any other `location` that could possibly match request.

In your case before you add auth, request to `/about/payment` was proceeded by `location /` which finally passed request to PHP. But as soon as you add `location /about/payment` request to that URL will be processed by this location which has no special directives so nginx will try to serve static files.

You should add directives that pass request to PHP, in this case it's really simple:

```
location /about/payment {
    auth_basic           "secured site";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/my.passwd;

    root ...;
    try_files $uri @symfonyapp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g. for Wordpress site, I wanna lock the URL

```
location ~* /block-url/ {
    auth_basic           "Internal Staging Site";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # Most important!
}
```